# Fasttext ignore wrong predictions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, fasttext

I have trained a fast text supervised model. I did used a pyfasttext python library to predict the model.
Ex: I have data like this.

```
text - label

The meeting is planned - event
The work should be finished - task
```

Here, the model predict the label correctly. when planned or the work words occurs in the sentence. But I have list sentences which are non-related to the trained data.
For ex: The dog is an animal

```
res = model.predict_proba_single('the dog is an animal\n')
```

output:

```
[(u'event', 0.49999999904767284)]
```

The output probability should be 0 or no label. Because the sentence is non relevant to all labels. The labels are multi-class. I gave example of two only.

Same thing also occurs in the scikit SGD classifier too.

How do I prevent this wrong prediction?

Comment: I think you just need more meaningful training data

Comment: Yes. I should. But, at realtime we may not know what will come into our prediction data set..!

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore prediction outputs less than a threshold  0.5 for example (50%) , by doing that you can just extract relevant prediction or printing 0 or no label for other irrelevant cases ,
hope that helps

Comment: Its not working. I'm getting various % Is there anyother way in this?

Comment: @GiriAnnamalaiM  can you give more details of your problem ? what is the accuracy of your model over the test set ? if your model is overfitting or underfitting , you need more data or use more complex models

Comment: No I have two labels and the train dataset are same in count. Accuracy is 94% over test set
Overfitting means either one of the label is higher count than other correct?

Comment: No overfiiting means that your model doe not generalize well on unseen data , but if your data are well balanced which mean you have pretty close numbers of example between your two classes , your model should perform well on unseen data , just in case you trained your model over your test set as well , if it's not the case i think my answer should work if  you ignore any prediction output less than a predefined threshold